# SQL Group by with min and corresponding values in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, grouping

Can I write a single query returning group by with min values and corresponding values in an optimized manner? Currently we are using multiple queries for the same.

eg:
A table has product category, product name, product id and price. I want to return the product type with min(price) but also product name and product id as well. This is in SQL 2008. Product name and product id can be duplicate

Edit 1: Added input and output for clarity
[image]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Comment: Perhaps you can write such query. How should we know?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The first note is that SQL is a declarative language; it declares a functional requirement, not how that requirement will be solved *(the SQL is 'compiled' in to an explain/execution plan, based on stats, indexes, hints, etc, etc, and then that's what is executed.)*.

That said, some SQL expressions are more costly than others.  Your case has a simple solution using analytic functions *(aka windowed functions)* that has a low cost due to scanning the table *(or appropriate index)* only once.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
   SELECT
      *,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY price)   AS category_price_rank
   FROM
      your_table
)
   ranked_your_table
WHERE
   category_price_rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT ProductCatg, ProductName, ProductID, MIN(PRICE), DateOrdered 
 FROM YOUR_TABLE 
 GROUP BY ProductCatg, ProductName, ProductID, DateOrdered ) A
 WHERE A.PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) 
                 FROM YOUR_TABLE 
                 WHERE ProductCatg = A.ProductCatg AND ProductName = A.ProductName )
```